# SQL Transaction Basics

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been hopping around SQL related forums quite a bit the last few days (I'm new) and I've been making some headway! However, I can't seem to crack this one. Here's my query:

```
USE EpiworksTest;

BEGIN TRANSACTION [tran3]
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT [Catalog].[TaskDefinition] ([ID], [WIPDesc], [SpecTable], [ResultsTable], [SpecFilePath], [SpecFileName], [SetupFilePath], [SetupFileName], [EWProduct], [Process], [Active], [CalcDur], [UnTimedEst], [ChamberUse], [DateCreated]) 
    VALUES (1, N'wp', N'spec', N'0', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'ew', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Catalog].[TaskDefinition] OFF
    INSERT [Catalog].[TaskStatus] ([ID], [Name], [Description]) 
    VALUES (1, N'Static', N'wat');
    COMMIT TRANSACTION [tran3]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [tran3]
END CATCH
```

I've checked and rechecked my table columns -- they match up with both of the Inserts here.
Both of my tables are currently empty. This query says it completes successfully but no rows are updated even though I have two Inserts! Any ideas? I've tried recreating my schema.
Will the SQL "compiler?" tell me if it has errors that I catch or tell me if it rolls any changes back? I have a feeling there's something funky going on with the try/catch or the transaction since that's what I've been getting to know today. Thanks for any responses.

Comment: please post the code to create the tables.

Comment: Try it in a test database without `.. transaction` and `try/catch`. Does it work? Evaluate the error value in the `catch` block. See example in [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

Comment: Or try putting `SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;` into CATCH block and see if it show anything

Comment: If you are trying to insert values into an identity field after setting identity_Insert off, it should throw an error and because of the error the control enters into catch block and rollback your insert both insert statements, And also since it is an insert statement you should be looking for new records not updated records in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the IDENTITY_INSERT option is OFF so you do not need to set it to off if you havent set it to ON. I think this is something what you are trying to do.

```
USE EpiworksTest;


BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION [tran3]; 

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Catalog].[TaskDefinition] ON;
    INSERT [Catalog].[TaskDefinition] ([ID], [WIPDesc], [SpecTable], [ResultsTable], [SpecFilePath], [SpecFileName], [SetupFilePath], [SetupFileName], [EWProduct], [Process], [Active], [CalcDur], [UnTimedEst], [ChamberUse], [DateCreated]) 
    VALUES (1, N'wp', N'spec', N'0', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'ew', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Catalog].[TaskDefinition] OFF;

    INSERT [Catalog].[TaskStatus] ([ID], [Name], [Description]) 
    VALUES (1, N'Static', N'wat');

    COMMIT TRANSACTION [tran3];
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
   BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [tran3];
   END

    SELECT  ERROR_MESSAGE()  AS [Error_Message]
           ,ERROR_LINE()     AS [Error_Line]
           ,ERROR_NUMBER()   AS [Error_Number]
           ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS [Error_Severity]

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

You are suppressing all errors so you never see them. This is a very severe anti-pattern and now you know why. Un-suppress errors. I suggest you add

```
THROW
```

to the catch block which rethrows the current error. Errors usually should bubble up to a place that can meaningfully handle and log them.

Comment: Good info! Let's say I have 2 errors in my try clause. Then I say `BEGIN CATCH` \n `THROW` Will both/all errors be thrown with just that?

Comment: I don't know. I avoid handling errors in T-SQL like the plague. I do it in C# which is better equipped to do that. I recommend that you just let all errors bubble up and make the app log them and kill the transaction. Use T-SQL control flow as little as possible. It is an inferior language made at a time where people could not even conceive of C#.

Comment: C# is the bomb :D F# looks interesting too. Thanks usr!